# Empty image response body when response header has correct length in IE and Fiddler

Tags: image, internet-explorer, ssl, jetty

there is a quite a bit of detail here:

1. Container: JETTY 7.62 and 7.69 (tried both)
2. Image: tried jpgs and
   pngs
3. Browser: IE9 and the Fiddler tool

So we have a web page that contains amongst other things a standard img tag. When we access the page from IE after the cache has been cleared we get a 200 for the image, infact this is what we see in

Request Header:

```
Key Value
Request GET /cc/auth/images/test.jpg HTTP/1.1
Accept  image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5
Accept-Language en-US
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    van-test-login9.login.dev.net:8443
Connection  Keep-Alive
```

Response Header:

```
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date    Thu, 28 Feb 2013 19:59:48 GMT
Content-Length  25926
Content-Type    image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8
Last-Modified   Thu, 28 Feb 2013 19:58:38 GMT
```

But the response body is empty.. on the server side we see

```
[28/Feb/2013:19:59:25 +0000] "GET /cc/auth/images/test.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 25926
```

So the image appears broken in the browser. We have been doing some experimenting by switching JETTY versions, that doesn't seem to make a difference. We don't see this issue using FF or Chrome. In addition if we go to port 8080 we can't recreate the issue either. So it seems to be a combination of SSL/JETTY/IE.

We can also recreate the problem by trying to access the image directly by typing in the resource location into the browser. We can recreate using Fiddler as well. There are no errors in our JETTY logs, application or otherwise.

I should also add this is intermittent.. once it happens if you keep hitting F5, eventually it will load and render, and then you don't see a broken image until you clear your cache.

Anyone out there have an suggestions or ideas how to figure out what is going on here?

Many Thanks

So a little more information, we have this in our web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

and

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

We did this to make sure that all our outgoing is UTF-8 What we didn't realise was that it would also put a charset everything including images!

Is there an easy way to filter out images?

Comment: OK so it seems that the cause behind this issue is the charset encoding for the image. IE doesn't like it..

Comment: I have the same problem with WebLogic 10.3.6 and IE11 with some newly added PNG images to my app. I have the same CharacterEncodingFilter but it does not add the encoding to the headers in case of images. I also disabled it completely to no help. The devtools in IE show that the loading of the img was Result: (Aborted). It happens over HTTPS only, HTTP is always OK.

Answer (score 1):

A very Jetty specific way to resolve this would be to use the rewrite handler to remove that charset in the response header.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler

I am not sure I would really recommend it but its possible.  We even have an IE specific rule in there for other IE historical oddness.  You could use an existing pattern based rewrite rule or create your own rule for this.

Likely better to address this in your app though.